# How to convert lowercase string to uppercase string without toUppercase() function

Tags: javascript

```
function alpha()
{
    var a=prompt("Enter String: ");

    for(var b=[i=0];c=a.charCodeAt(i);)
    {
        b[i++]=String.fromCharCode(c|(c>96 && c<123));
    }
    alert(b.join(""))
}
console.log(alpha());
```

So far some letters in the code change when I run this but for some reason it is not changing the string characters to all uppercase. (Example of output; I type "hi" into the prompt and the alert outputs "i" so the h disappears for some reason.

Comment: Subtract 32 from the character code if the character is between 97 and 123.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `toUpperCase` forbidden?

Comment: @gyre from what I understand, his code is buggy and therefore he is looking for an alternative to the toUpperCase function. With at said... Tiago, you should find out why the code is not working rather than re-create a toUpperCase function.

Comment: Why this strange initialization `var b = [i = 0]`? If you want to initialize two variables, use `var b = [], i = 0`

Comment: What do you think `var b=[i=0]` does for you that `var b=[], i=0` wouldn't? You're creating a one-element array and then the first iteration of the loop overwrites that element. Also, you're creating a global `i`. (Also, when I run your code and type "hi", I get "ii", not "i".)

Comment: @gyre It's obviously an academic exercise, to learn how something like `toUppercase` is implemented.

Comment: @TiagoSa what are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you need to change all the characters in your string to uppercase? You might be over-thinking the entire situation...

Comment: @Barmar (That is the answer I was expecting, but I was hoping to hear a little more context from OP.)

Comment: @gyre I have a series of problems where one would normally code using built-in functions, but the only rule for these problems is to not use the built-in functions. Therefore I have to try and find a way to code without using the built in function to gain a greater knowledge of Javascript. But I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Easy, use `toLocaleUpperCase()`

Comment: @Barmar 
b[i++]=String.fromCharCode(c|(c>97 && c<123)-32);
subtracting 32 should work but for some reason it's not, its returning symbols instead of uppercase characters. I tried switching up the numbers and adding 32 so I now know how to make it go to lowercase without the use of the built-in functions but the uppercase is not working yet

Comment: Why are you using `|` in there?

Comment: The bit flipping technique works on 140 out of 944 letters that have a different form as lowercase. (Of course, that's culture/locale dependent so those numbers are for at least one culture.) You'd be best off by creating an explicit mapping that covers the letters and cultures you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function alpha()
{
    var a=prompt("Enter String: ");
    var output="";
    for(var x=0;x<a.length;x++)
            output+=String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(x)>96 && a.charCodeAt(x)<123 ? a.charCodeAt(x)-32: a.charCodeAt(x))
    return output;
}
console.log("--" + alpha());
```

Just get the ascii code for each char, and if it ranges between 97 to 122 ( a to z ) deduct 32 from val to get the corresponding upper case char. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be so much easier to read if you had `var c = a.charCodeAt(x)`  and then used `c` in the calculation instead of `a.charCodeAt(x)` four times in one line.

Comment: yup, true that :=)

Answer (score 2):

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) mentioned in the comments above:

> Subtract 32 from the character code if the character is between 97 and 123.

You can make your looping logic a little clearer with a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)-[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)-[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) combination.

Since you can also compare single-character strings in JavaScript, like `'a' < 'b'`, this can further reduce the amount of code needed to handle the conversion of  character codes.

```js
function alpha (s) {
  return s.split('').map(function (c) {
    return 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' ? String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) - 32) : c
  }).join('')
}

console.log(
  alpha(prompt("Enter String: "))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do.

```js
function alpha() {
  var a = prompt("Enter string: ");

  var upper = a.split('').map((e) => e.charCodeAt(0) > 96 && e.charCodeAt(0) < 123 ? String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(0) - 32) : e);

  return upper.join('');
}

console.log(alpha());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest's sake, here's a way to do it in one statement without arrays or a loop (at least, not an explicit loop):

```js
var input = 'ABCdefGHIjkl123.'  // or you could prompt("Enter String: ")

var output = input.replace(/[a-z]/g, function(m) {
  return String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) - 32)
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a learning objective, I will only described a means to do this and let you try to figure it out using this answer as a guideline.

first you want to loop through the characters in string.
for each character you would want some code to turn it into a capital letter, assuming it is a letter.
finally you want to hold the capitalized letters in a variable.

This link may help for UTF-8 charcodes. Even if you aren't using utf-8, it may give you some ideas. 
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: That's the algorithm in his question. His issue is that he doesn't know how to turn the letter into a capital letter.

Comment: as i see it, everyone seems to be making this more complicated than it needs to be. Though as a hint, it'll throw in a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to implement it **without calling any functions at all**:

```js
function myToUpper(string) {
  var map = { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C', d: 'D', e: 'E', f: 'F', g: 'G', h: 'H', i: 'I', j: 'J', k: 'K', l: 'L', m: 'M', n: 'N', o: 'O', p: 'P', q: 'Q', r: 'R', s: 'S', t: 'T', u: 'U', v: 'V', w: 'W', x: 'X', y: 'Y', z: 'Z' }

  var output = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
    output += map[string[i]] || string[i]

  return output
}

console.log( myToUpper('ABCdefGHIjkl123.') )   // 'ABCDEFGHIJKL123.'
```

Comment: Not allowed to use myToUpper

Comment: @TiagoSa - What do you mean? Why not? `myToUpper()` is the function *I* wrote as shown in my answer, so why aren't you allowed to use it? It could've been called `alpha()` like your own function, but that is not a meaningful function name.

Comment: Oh ok i thought you were using it as a function, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// code for change the string to lower case to upper case

const upperCase = ()=>{

    let welcome = prompt("Enter your string");
let upper = '';
for(let i=0; i<welcome.length;i++){
    code =  welcome.charCodeAt(i);

   if(code >= 97 && code <= 122){
    let co = code-32;
    console.log(co);
    upper += String.fromCharCode(co);
   }
   else
   {
    upper +=String.fromCharCode(code) ;
   }
   console.log(upper);
}
}
```